# AngularJS auto submit form

Tags: angularjs, forms, submit

I need to submit a form on AngularJS. It's a search form, using Elastic Search. Sometimes the search don't bring any result, and i need to click on the button again.

It's possible to "re-submit" a form automatically if there are results on the search?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use (onclick) directive like this :

```
<button(onclick)='test()'>Submit</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

call the click programatically

```
angular.element('#myButton').triggerHandler('click');
```

or submit the form by doing

```
form.$setSubmitted();
```

Comment: from the angular element docs `If jQuery is available, angular.element is an alias for the jQuery function. If jQuery is not available, angular.element delegates to AngularJS's built-in subset of jQuery, called "jQuery lite" or jqLite.` the setsubmitted on the form is just ngForm FormController

Comment: @MatheusSartori did this help you?

Comment: Yes, i fixed the issue on my system. Ty!

Comment: please accept my answer if it helped you so future visitors know where to look